# how to add an existing script to uft using AOM/vbScript?

Tags: quality-center, hp-uft, vbscript

So I have a script which connects to QC and opens a test in UFT and runs it. 
The problem with this is that the open command closes the previously opened tests. 
I want to copy the file -> add -> existing test functionality in my vbScript.

Thanking you in advance.